# Alert is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really not understand why alert is not working
HERE IS MY HTML

```
<div class='main'>
    <div class="head">
        <div class="check">
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" class="myinput large" id="click" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>DEMO</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

HERE IS MY JS

```
$('#click').click(function () {
    $("#app").fadeToggle(this.checked);
    if($("#app").is(' :checked')){
    alert('hi')
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/7503/)

Comment: Because `#app` is a div and divs can't be checked?

Comment: I can't see #app in your html.

Comment: `is not working` - everyone do a shot!

Comment: You have no `id="app"` in your html, so ...

Comment: Could you explain what your are expecting your code to do. It seems a little unclear what your intentions are given that the selectors don't match the HTML markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` instead of `$("#app")`

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
   alert('hi')
}
```

Comment: This is also a working answer.  Not sure why someone is downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong selector.  Try this:

```
if ($('#click').is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: I love the folks downvoting an answer that actually works with no explanation.  http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/7504/

Comment: This does work! I would not downvote necessarily, but do note that reselecting the object with it's ID causes jQuery to have to find the element. Using this will prevent that lookup and speed it up.

Comment: @MikelBitson Totally agreed, I just didn't want to confuse the situation for someone obviously new to jQuery.  But I definitely did upvote the other answers that mention this.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's not 100% clear that this is what the OP wants. For example MLP interpreted it that the OP wants to check if `#app` is visible (given that `#app` refers to a div later in the HTML.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are a few issues, but mostly the selector on your if is incorrect. Looking at your JSBIN, the $('#app') fade does have an element to operate on, so I'm sure you've got that fine. Try this:

```
$('#click').click(function () {
    $("#app").fadeToggle(this.checked);
    if($(this).is(' :checked')){
        alert('hi')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong :

```
$('#click').click(function () {
  $("#app").fadeToggle(this.checked);
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
     alert('hi')
  }
});
```

If you want to check the app, use this condition :

```
if($("#app").is(':visible')){
     alert('hi')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/7505/

Changes:

```
$('#click').click(function () {
    $("#app").fadeToggle(this.checked);
    if($("#click").is(' :checked')){
    alert('hi');
    }
});
```